# Automatically save a send email as Adobe PDF and save in a folder

Tags: automation, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, adobe, power-automate

I would like to create an automatic step whenever I send certain emails with the subject line "Filing" and email body containing "filing done" to save these send emails as Adobe PDF inside my personal folder.

May I know how can I go about creating this?

Comment: I don't think you have an automatic option available for this. Being said that, you can try one of the following approaches: (1) Use Microsoft Flow, when the mail is sent trigger the action to save as PDF and save it in folder (2) Create Outlook native Outlook Object Model API to send email, save it as PDF (natively this option is not  available, but you can reference the PDF conversion libraries to achieve this) and save it in folder... Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Moving this to answer. Consider upvoting it; so it can be useful to others too.

Comment: Create Outlook native Outlook Object Model API to send email, save it as PDF referencing Word Object model. Here's an example (https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/save-outlook-email-pdf/) how you can make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have an automatic/in-built option available for this from native Outlook perspective. Being said that, you can try one of the following approaches:

- Use
  Microsoft Flow, when the mail is sent trigger the action to save as
  PDF and save it in folder
- Create Outlook native Outlook Object
  Model API to send email, save it as PDF referencing Word Object model. Here's an [example](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/save-outlook-email-pdf/) how you can make use of it.

Comment: Hi Dev! Thank you for answering! May I know how do I create the Flow steps to convert into PDF?

Comment: Here you go - https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/save-email-as-pdf/td-p/109005

Comment: I encountered an error in the "Convert file" step. https://imgur.com/a/1t9n3pW May I know how can I resolve it?